# +1 on IPv4 input string in a bash script

Tags: bash, ip

I'm trying to make a script in bash to ping to addresses at once.
The adressess are always 1 over the one the user keyed in.

Example:
What is the ip?
192.168.0.10

The program should ping 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.11. Finally it should give ping output.

I have problems incrementing on the last digit of the ip.
My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script for å pinge to lokasjoner samtidig.

read input
echo $input
ip1=$input

let "ip2=$input+1"

echo $ip1
echo $ip2
```

As you can see, I have a long way to go. But my first question is how to increment only the last digits of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk alternative:

```
ip="192.168.0.10"
ip2=$(awk -F\. '{ print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4+1 }' <<< $ip )
echo $ip2
192.168.0.11
```

Read the original ip address into awk and separate fields with "." Add 1 to the last field and then set this into the variable ip2

Comment: this will fail if the last octet is 255

Answer (score 4):

using variable expansion and arithmetic expansion

```
ip2=${ip1%.*}.$((${ip1##*.}+1))
```

- `${ip1%.*}` removes the shortest suffix .* (last number)
- `${ip1##*.}` removes the largest prefix *. (all except last number)

Comment: this will give `192.168.011
` - missed `.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your `ip1` octets separately:

```
part1=${ip1%.*}"."     # first 3 octets (with trailing separator `.`)
part2=${ip1##*.}       # last octet
ip2=$part1$[$part2+1]

printf "%s\n%s\n" $ip1 $ip2
```

The exemplary output:

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
```